# Changing theme attribute when usage

Tags: flutter, themes

I created `popupMenuTheme`. I need to use it twice. The first one is typical of the theme, and the second has a little difference of `fontWeight`, so I need to inherit all properties but the `fontWeight` attribute, but when I do so the popup menu converted into a white container.

Theme code:

```
 popupMenuTheme: theme.popupMenuTheme.copyWith(
                color: const Color(pagesBackgroundColor),
                elevation: 3,
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: const Color(accentColor),
                  fontFamily:
                      Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode == 'ar'
                          ? 'almasry'
                          : 'patrick',
                  fontSize: 3.5.h,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
```

Updated theme code:

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    popupMenuTheme:const PopupMenuThemeData(
      textStyle: TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
  ))),
  child: PopupMenuButton(
    itemBuilder: (context) => const [
      PopupMenuItem(child: Text("update")),
      PopupMenuItem(child: Text("delete")),
    ],
    icon: const Icon(
      Icons.more_vert,
      color: Color(accentColor),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use it like following

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    popupMenuTheme: PopupMenuTheme.of(context).copyWith(
      textStyle: PopupMenuTheme.of(context).textStyle.copyWith(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
    ),
  ),
  child: PopupMenuButton(
    itemBuilder: (context) => const [
      PopupMenuItem(child: Text("update")),
      PopupMenuItem(child: Text("delete")),
    ],
    icon: const Icon(
      Icons.more_vert,
      color: Color(accentColor),
    ),
  ),
),
```